# Problem with setting wwwroot by session with TinyMCE FileManager

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I'm trying to set different values for TinyMCE through ASP .NET Session.
In the web.config for File Manager the SessionAuthenticator is set up with

```
<add key="SessionAuthenticator.config_prefix" value="filemanager" />
```

So in a MVC controller I do

```
Session["filemanager.preview.urlprefix"] = "{proto}://{host}/edunet/";
```

Which works, the value is used in the same way as when I do it through the config.

```
Session["filemanager.preview.wwwroot"] = @"C:\Projekt\EduNet\app\EduNet.Web";
```

Doesn't have any effect.
If I set the value in web.config like

```
<add key="preview.wwwroot" value="C:\Projekt\EduNet\app\EduNet.Web" />
```

It works.

The override value is set as

```
<add key="preview.allow_override" value="*" />
```

Help!